# Why does NHibernate say my filter isn't configured?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-configuration

I'm trying to use a global filter in NHibernate, and as far as I can tell I'm doing exactly what all the tutorials do, but I'm getting an exception.

My .hbm.xml file contains the following:

```xml
...
<class name="NHibernateSandbox.Foo, NHibernateSandbox" table="Foo">
    ...
    <property column="Content" type="String" name="Content" not-null="true" length="100" />
    <property column="Deleted" type="Boolean" name="Deleted" not-null="true" />
    <filter name="Foo_Nondeleted" condition="Deleted = false" />
</class>
```

Then I have a simple test class:

```cs
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure();

using (ISessionFactory sf = cfg.BuildSessionFactory()) {
    using (ISession session = sf.OpenSession()) {
        session.EnableFilter("Foo_Nondeleted");
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("FROM NHibernateSandbox.Foo");
        foreach (Foo foo in query.List<Foo>()) {
            Console.WriteLine(foo.Content);
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the `EnableFilter` line it works as expected: both deleted and undeleted rows are printed. However, with the `EnableFilter` line I get an NHibernateException

```
No such filter configured [Foo_Nondeleted]
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetFilterDefinition(String filterName)
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.EnableFilter(String filterName)
  at NHibernateSandbox.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

If I configure log4net to be verbose then I see

```
INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: NHibernateSandbox.Foo -> Foo
DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.HbmBinder - Mapped property: Id -> RID, type: Int32
DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.HbmBinder - Mapped property: Content -> Content, type: String
DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.HbmBinder - Mapped property: Deleted -> Deleted, type: Boolean
DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.HbmBinder - Applying filter [Foo_Nondeleted] as [Deleted = false]
```

What's the missing step between it "applying filter" and the filter being "configured" and available to the session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not enough to add a filter to the class: you have to define it as well. This comes down to adding

```xml
<filter-def name="Foo_Nondeleted"></filter-def>
```

to the .hbm.xml file. Note that there's a catch here: although tutorials show it before the classes, it has to be placed after them in the XML or you'll get an `XmlSchemaValidationException`.

There's another small change which needs to be made too: even though you might have `query.substitutions` set up to map `false` to `0`, it isn't applied to the filter condition, so you'll have to change the filter to

```xml
<filter name="Foo_Nondeleted" condition="Deleted = 0" />
```